# Cryptography in java bytes to bits

Tags: java

I wrote server and client and I would like to send some file which will be encrypted. So I have to operate on bits, not bytes, because my cryptography metod is like that: I send my file in parts of about 8 bits and I add to them some specific MAC. (its: winnowing and Chaffing metod)

In my program I read file into byte array. But I need byte to bits to add MAC adress to each part of file and send them in parts.

My question is:
Is there any posibility to operate on bits in Java, or if not how would you solve this problem?

Comment: 8 bits is a single byte. You're really going to send your file *one byte at a time*? Are you inventing your own encryption scheme here? That's almost *always* a bad idea.

Comment: The same basic bit shifting options as are available in C and C++ are available in Java. What bit twiddling operations are you looking for?

Comment: The [`Chaffing and Winnowing`](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/chaffing-980701.txt) method looks interesting. But I'd say it was invented just to prove that encryption is not required for confidentiality, not as a serious mechanism to securely transmit data. http://www.wired.com/techbiz/media/news/1998/03/11127

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use SSL or TLS? Or any other built in security protocol. It seems weird to re-invent the wheel here.

Often, proprietary encryption systems are less secure than well known ones, because they have not been subject to public scrutiny.

The fact that nobody knows about it does not make it more secure. "Security by Obscurity" is never the best practice.

Comment: Yep of course I would like, but this is my project for university:P

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think your problem will be solved by converting bytes to bits, but here's how you can do it.

```
static boolean[] byteToBits(byte b) {
  boolean[] bits = new boolean[8];
  for (int idx = 0; idx < 8; ++idx) 
    bits[idx] = ((b >> idx) & 1) == 1;
  return bits;
}
```